# Connect to oracle server using siebel tools

Tags: siebel

I need to connect to the oracle server using Siebel tools. 
First I created an ODBC Data Source and tested the connection. It was successful.

So is there any other configurations to be done within the tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a .cfg file which has the ServerDataSrc pointing to the server TNS entry. The ODBC data source is required during checkin/checkout operations. Refer this [link](http://siebelunleashed.com/siebel-crm-configuration-file-cfg-disected-and-explained/) to understand the .cfg parameters.

Comment: Do I need to add the name of the Server Name as the ConnectString parameter. Current value is SIEBEL

Comment: I have added my data source name as the ServerDataSrc's connecstring in both tools.cgf and scomm.cfg.

Any other configurations??